# Search result title truncated before square brackets

Tags: support, google, seo

When I was searching on Google I saw this question with weird title:

[image: search result]

and this is the actual page [How should we retrieve an individual post now that /[post-id] is deprecated in v2.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353591/how-should-we-retrieve-an-individual-post-now-that-post-id-is-deprecated-in-v)

Seems like the title was truncated up to the square brackets, could this be a bug on Google's side or Stack Overflow's?

Comment: What was your query? Google does sometimes change titles based on your input query. See [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en). [This query](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=How+should+we+retrieve+an+individual+post+now+that&oq=How+should+we+retrieve+an+individual+post+now+that&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.77j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) shows the text in full.

Comment: I searched "singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher"
https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=singular+statuses+API+is+deprecated+for+versions+v2.4+and+higher&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=dhJjWeXNK4jAtAefy6XwDA

Comment: We provide the correct open graph title on the page (look for `og:title`). What google does with that... isn't under our control :(

Comment: > Scroll to bottom of Google results. > Find "feedback" link > Give feedback about how this title looks dumb.

Comment: @Oded google doesn't read og tags for search https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en and throws an error on the SDTT https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F31353591%2Fhow-should-we-retrieve-an-individual-post-now-that-post-id-is-deprecated-in-v

Comment: @Braiam - we do provide the correct meta title/description tags as well. Again - not much we can do about how Google uses them.

Comment: Something weird is going on at google. If you search for the title of that question on Google, you get the right title. If you search for the Stack Overflow URL of that question, you also get the right title. Also, if you remove some words from the search, for example if you search for "singular statuses API", you also get the right title.

Comment: The word that triggers the cutoff is "deprecated."  Again, > Scroll to bottom of Google results. > Find "feedback" link > Give feedback about how this title looks dumb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not aware, Google [reserves the right to show something different if it feels that is more relevant to the search](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en) (emphasis mine)

> If we’ve detected that a particular result has one of the above issues with its title, we may try to generate an improved title from anchors, on-page text, or other sources. However, sometimes even pages with well-formulated, concise, descriptive titles will end up with different titles in our search results to better indicate their relevance to the query. There’s a simple reason for this: the title tag as specified by a webmaster is limited to being static, fixed regardless of the query. **Once we know the user’s query, we can often find alternative text from a page that better explains why that result is relevant.** Using this alternative text as a title helps the user, and it also can help your site. Users are scanning for their query terms or other signs of relevance in the results, and a title that is tailored for the query can increase the chances that they will click through.

So Google is apparently matching something relevant to

> singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher

[image]

but not in other terms like

> facebook individual post deprecated in 2.4

[image]

Since it's clearly been indexed properly, my bet is that people are searching for different strings and Google is picking the relevant one for this. So it's not anything SO can control or even complain to Google about.